# How to detect something does not exist before 'end of string' in regex

Tags: regex

I have a simple regular expression looking for twitter style tags in a string like so:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})/";
```

This works great for matching words after an @ sign.

One thing it does though which I don't want it to do is match full stops.

So it should match

"@foo"

but should not match

"@foo."

I tried adding amending the expression to dissallow full stops like so:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})[^\.]/";
```

This almost works, except it will not match if it's at the end of the string. EG:

It WILL match this "@foo more text here"

but won't match this "@foo"

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Simple. It is `$` symbol for end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working if it's at the end of the string because it's expecting `[^\.]` after it.

What you are wanting, you can do with a negative lookahead to make sure there is no dot afterwards, like this:

```
/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})(?![^\.]*\.)/
```

[image]

[**Test it here**](http://www.debuggex.com/r/bsAnH5Q7Vu1C4F5M)

---

You could also do it this way:

```
/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})([^\.]*)$/
```

[image]

[**Test it here**](http://www.debuggex.com/r/-Hfcy8TBONGHiD8P)

This one allows for optional characters other than a dot, and then it has to be the end of the string.

Comment: this won't match if there is a dot after the string

Comment: Yay, and I beg your pardon

Comment: This seems to work as I wanted and also thanks for the link to that cook site.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your original expression can be written like the following:

```
/@\w{1,15}/
```

because `\w` is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

Secondly your expression doesn't match names with `.` so you probably meant that you don't want to match names ending with a dot and this can be done with the following:

```
/@\w{1,15}(?![^\.]*\.)/
```

Or if you want to match a name no matter how long it is just not ending with a dot then

```
/@\w+(?![^\.]\.)/
```

Oh ya, I forgot one thing, your problem was caused by the absence of any anchor characters such as the start of line `^` and end of line `$`, so you should use them if you want to match a string that contains only a twitter name which you wish to validate.

**Summary:** If you want to match names anywhere in the document don't use anchors, and if you want to know whether a given string is a valid name use the anchors.

Answer (score 1):

A `$` matches the end of the string, and for future reference, a `^` matches the begining:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})$/";
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what the OP wants. He wants to match stuff like "@foo more text here", just as long as there isn't a `\.` after the capture group.